# Unwanted margin in DropdownMenu in TextInputLayout

Tags: android, kotlin, layout

im having a problem with margin in my TextInputLayout. Below picture of problem. It gets very ugly especially when there is 1 element in list.

[image]

Posting my code and style below. Tried getting rid of this padding programmaticaly but maybe thats some issue with style itself.

```
<style name="AppTheme.TextInput.Dropdown" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense.ExposedDropdownMenu">
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">
        @style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox.Dense
    </item>
    <item name="boxBackgroundColor">@color/colorBackground</item>
    <item name="boxBackgroundMode">filled</item>
</style>
```

And this is how i make it in code. "view" is the container for elements

```
  private fun addDictionaryField(layoutParams: ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams, formField: FormField): View {
        val view = TextInputLayout(ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.AppTheme_TextInput_Dropdown))
        view.layoutParams = layoutParams

        val autoCompleteTextView = AutoCompleteTextView(ContextThemeWrapper(view.context, R.style.AppTheme_AutoCompleteEditText))
        autoCompleteTextView.minEms = 4
        autoCompleteTextView.maxEms = 6
        autoCompleteTextView.isSingleLine = true
        autoCompleteTextView.hint = formField.name
        autoCompleteTextView.textSize = formField.fontSize?.toFloat() ?: 16F
        autoCompleteTextView.dropDownHorizontalOffset = 0
        autoCompleteTextView.dropDownWidth = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT

        //if (formField.fontColor != "auto" ) autoCompleteTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(formField.fontColor))
        //if (formField.backgroundColor != "auto" ) autoCompleteTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(formField.backgroundColor))

        autoCompleteTextView.isEnabled = false

        val structure = fillFormViewModel.getDictionaryStructure(formField.dictionaryStructure)

        if (structure != null) {
            if (structure.parentId == null) {
                autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(loadDictionaryFields(structure, null, null))
                autoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener { parent, _, position, _ ->
                    fillFormViewModel.dictionarySelectedElements[formField.id!!] = (parent.adapter.getItem(position) as DictionaryField).id!!
                    loadChildStructureFields(formField.dictionaryGroup, parent.adapter.getItem(position) as DictionaryField, null, null)
                }
            }
        }

        view.addView(autoCompleteTextView)
        return view
   }
```

This is how i like it to look (except for this is not dropdown choice menu)
[image]

Anyone had simmilar problem by any chance ? :)

Answer (score 0):

Had to change padding in style becouse it had some padding by default

< item name= "android:padding">0dp< /item >